# Google Sheets Validation lookup to return different result

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to do a Validation Dropdown List of Abbreviations but the returned string must be the full string.

For eg... Validation dropdown will show various Country Abbreviations, but once I select it, the result needs to return the full Country Title and not the Abbreviation.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Column A1 has a dropdown that contains "US", "UK", "AU", etc. When I select one, for Example "US". The value within the same cell then becomes "United States" instead of "US".

Comment: it's possible to do it with formulas but you would need to do double selection in the dropdown menu where you first select abbreviation and then you can change it to full title. also note that this will come with red triangle in the corner. (let me know if you are still interested) - otherwise, you will need a script